# Problema com configuração log4j

Tags: java, apache, log4j

Como faço para configurar as propriedades do log4j? Na minha aplicação, estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.docx4j.jaxb.Context).
>
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>
> log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Procurando pela internet, encontrei a seguinte sugestão:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/systemprops.html#Specification

Porém, como faço para mudar para false a propriedade abaixo?

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES
```

Segue abaixo o meu arquivo de configuração do `log4j.properties`:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1. log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender. log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout. log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.A1.Target=System.out

# An alternative logging format:
# log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n


#Prevent internal log4j DEBUG messages from polluting the output. log4j.logger.org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator=INFO log4j.logger.org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter=INFO log4j.logger.org.apache.log4j.FileAppender=INFO
```

Comment: Posta sua configuração, você está usando o log4J 1 ou 2 ?

Comment: Estou utilizando o log4j-1.2.17

Comment: Você tem problemas em mudar para o logj2? a uns meses tive muitos problemas com o 1 mudei para o 2 e acabaram os problemas :D, posta sua configuração que eu coloco uma resposta de como configurar ele.

Comment: Não tenho problemas não. Acabei de editar minha pergunta adicionando o arquivo de propriedades, espero que seja este. Se vc puder me ajudar a configurar ele, fico muito agradecido! :D

Comment: conseguiu resolver? @Duds

Comment: Agora deu certo! Muito obrigado @Wellington Avelino

Comment: Se a resposta foi util, marque como certa para ajudar outros usuarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Duds**

Exemplos da configuração do log4j 1 e 2.

Existe a possibilidade de fazer apenas via código Java, caso seja do seu interesse.

O log4j1 precisa estar no arquivo `log4j.properties` dentro da pasta `WEB-INF` do seu projeto(se for projeto web).

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout, fileout //define o nivel 

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%c{1}:%L %-5p %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %t - %m%n 

log4j.appender.fileout=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender //eu configurei para todo dia gerar um novo arquivo
log4j.appender.fileout.File=\\caminho onde você deseja salvar o arquivo
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd \\configuração para criação do arquivo 
log4j.appender.fileout.Append=true
log4j.appender.fileout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p] %c:%L - %m%n
```

Configuração do **Log4j2**, este precisa ser em aquivo **XML** e ficar dentro da pasta source do seu projeto

```
src 
|-pacotes
|-arquivo log4j2.xml
```

### LOG4J.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
<Properties>
<Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
<RollingFile name="file-log" fileName=""// caminho pra o arquivo a ser gerado
filePattern="c:/hrwms/log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
<PatternLayout>
<pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
<Policies>
<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
</Policies>
</RollingFile>

<Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
<PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
</Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<Logger name="//geralmente uso o nome do pacote ou classe aqui" level="info" additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="file-log" level="info"/>
</Logger>
<Root level="info" additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="console"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

### Para ilustrar o uso nas classes :

```
Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Teste.class);

log.info("Falha na validação dos parâmetros (" + e.getMessage() + ")");

//ou

log.info("Lote " + paramLote);
```

### JARS:

```
log4j-api-2.3.jar

log4j-core-2.3.jar
```

Caso não utilize Maven

As configurações são muito parecidas da versão 1 para o 2, não sei qual a sua estratégia para os logs, mas no [site oficial](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) eles mostram certinho tudo que você precisa para uma boa configuração.