# Como configurar o Log4J do Apache para gravar no Banco através do Hibernate?

Tags: xml, java-ee, hibernate, apache, log4j

Estou começando a usar o Log4J da Apache e gostaria de saber como configurá-lo pelo arquivo XML para gravar os logs no banco usando o hibernate?

Comment: Quem negativou a pergunta poderia pelo menos dizer o motivo? Vamos nos ajudar pessoal! :)

Comment: Concordo plenamente

Comment: a postagem foi negativa provavelmente pq é uma questão muito 'boba', não me leve a mal, mas meia hora lendo a documentação outro motivo é que é uma questão muito ampla, ao invés de perguntar 'como usar tal ferramenta' direcione sua pergunta, por exemplo 'como configurar ferramenta x com uma base de dados y' respondendo à sua questão principal, vc pode encontrar como configurar o log4j com xml, properties e diretamente em java em seu [manual oficial](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html), também recomendo ver alguns [exemplos no github do projeto](https://github.com/apache/log4j)

Comment: talvez te ajude, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80340/10315

Comment: Exatamente @re22 , basicamente tudo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tiago Ferezin**

**Gravando em uma tabela os logs LOG4J1**:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, DB

# Define the DB appender
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender

# Set JDBC Options
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.DB.user=root
log4j.appender.DB.password=password

# Set the SQL statement to be executed.
log4j.appender.DB.sql=insert into logging values('%d{yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss.SSS}','%C','%p','%m')

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Você precisa ter uma tabela já criada para gravar os dados no banco o uso continua sendo o mesmo, apenas irá gravar na tabela especificada.

**Utilizando na classe Java**

```
Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Teste.class);

log.info("Falha na validação dos parâmetros (" + e.getMessage() + ")");

//ou

log.info("Lote " + paramLote);
```

**Logar atividades do HIBERNATE** *(Essa parte é apenas para registrar o que o hibernate executa*)

Retirei desta [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436687/3861347) como obter os logs do hibernate, acredito que os níveis também possam ser gravados na base

Lista das categorias de LOGS:

```
Category                    Function

org.hibernate.SQL           Log all SQL DML statements as they are executed
org.hibernate.type          Log all JDBC parameters
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl  Log all SQL DDL statements as they are executed
org.hibernate.pretty        Log the state of all entities (max 20 entities) associated with the session at flush time
org.hibernate.cache         Log all second-level cache activity
org.hibernate.transaction   Log transaction related activity
org.hibernate.jdbc          Log all JDBC resource acquisition
org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST   Log HQL and SQL ASTs during query parsing
org.hibernate.secure        Log all JAAS authorization requests
org.hibernate               Log everything (a lot of information, but very useful for troubleshooting)
```

Configuração já formatada para colocar no seu arquivo log4j

```
 <!-- Registra todas as instruções SQL DML que são executados -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" />
<!-- Registra todas as instruções os parametros JDBC -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="debug" />
<!-- Registra todas as instruções SQL DDLque são executados -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl" level="debug" />
<!-- Registra o estado de todas as entidades (máximo de 20 entidades) associados com a sessão em tempo de limpeza -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.pretty" level="debug" />
<!--Registra todas as atividades cache de segundo nível -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.cache" level="debug" />
<!-- Registra atividades de transação relacionada -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.transaction" level="debug" />
<!-- Registra toda aquisição de recursos JDBC -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.jdbc" level="debug" />
<!-- Registra HQL e SQL durante a análise da consulta -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST" level="debug" />
<!-- Registea todos os pedidos de autorização JAAS -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.secure" level="debug" />
<!-- Registrar tudo (um monte de informações, mas muito útil para a solução de problemas) -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate" level="debug" />
```

Existem diversos niveis de depuração no LOG4J, você pode usar o:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
```

Este nivel de LOG **ALL** vai logar tudo e deve ser colocado antes do seu elemento raiz no arquivo.

Informações extras sobre [JDBCappender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender)

**Extra:** Caso ainda precise configurar o LOG4J no seu projeto existe essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80340/10315) no SOpt

Comment: Fiz dessa maneira porem ainda nao esta persistindo no banco.

Comment: Você criou a tabela e especificou tudo certinho? eu testei e deu tudo certo.
Apresenta algum erro?@TiagoFerezin

Comment: O ponto chave é configurar o primeiro arquivo para logar no banco, os 3 ultimos sção apenas para logar as peculiaridades do hibernate

Comment: @TiagoFerezin, conseguiu?

Comment: Sim eu consegui deu certo