# Log de erro em aplicação Java

Tags: java, log

Nós desenvolvedores quando codificamos, temos como acompanhar o processo de execução de um software por meio da saída do IDE, mas quando o software vai para produção e não temos mais o ambiente de desenvolvimento, como podemos mapear um erro que aconteceu durante algum processo do sistema.

Como registraria em um *log*?

Comment: Acredito que normalmente se você estiver utilizando Java em alguma aplicação a própria JVM fica encarregada de salvar um log caso ocorrer um `NullPointerException`, por exemplo. Qualquer coisa você pode criar um arquivo `.txt` para gravar os erros.

Comment: Clayton, eu uso o LOG4J, tem uma resposta minha [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80340/10315) de como utilizar e configurar

Comment: Desconhecia Wellington, obrigado por sua resposta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É difícil fazer um tutorial completo, fugiria do foco do site.

Você deve ter uma classe que trate disto para você. O ideal é usar uma que já faça todo o trabalho sem grandes preocupações. Uma classe conhecida vai lhe poupar um monte de dor de cabeça do que tentar fazer sozinho. Aí é seguir a documentação.

Em essência você deve invocar o *log* sempre que achar que deve. Ou seja, quando alguma coisa que puder validar e der erro ou quando ocorrer exceções. Lembrando que o que *loggar* e o que deixar de fora é uma decisão do programador. O mais comum é *loggar* quando ocorre exceções. Mas como a cultura do Java é causar exceções até mesmo quando não há um erro de fato e pode se recuperar, nem sempre é interessante *loggar* todas exceções. Dá para ter níveis diferentes de "erro".

Outro exemplo do que deve decidir é se vai *loggar* erros momentâneos e que são recuperados, como em acesso à arquivos ou rede que falham, por exemplo.

Portanto dentro de `catch` é o local onde mais fará o *log*. É provável que tenha inclusive algo assim no seu `main()`:

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ClassePrincipal.class);
try {
    chamaAplicacao();
} catch (Exception ex) { //o único lugar onde capturar Exception faz sentido
    log.error("um erro ocorreu: " + ex.getMessage()); //talvez um printStackTrace() tb
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Log.java).

Acredito que a biblioteca de *log* mais usada seja a [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/).

Este é só um exemplo básico usando ela, claro que a utilização completa precisa ser acompanhada de boa leitura no manual.

Em outros locais, [evite capturar `Exception`, capture a exceção mais específica possível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101).

Se achar que deve fazer algo próprio, estude esta biblioteca para bolar algo parecido. Mas não aconselho.

Comment: Só um adendo não precisa chamar .getName(); o log4j aceita `ClassePrincipal.class`

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino legal, melhorado. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

A parte de configuração de log no Java tem uma história que pode parecer um pouco confusa no início.

A opção de log que vem por padrão com o Java está no pacote `java.util.logging`. Você pode usá-la simplesmente [fazendo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950557/good-examples-using-java-util-logging):

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName());
```

Ele fornece vários tipos de níveis de log. Como exemplo, ao capturar uma exceção:

```
try {
    // codigo com erro
} catch( Exception ex ) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.toString(), ex);
}
```

Contudo, esta implementação do Java tinha suas [limitações](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359187/why-not-use-java-util-logging) quando foi lançada. Isto abriu espaço para outras alternativas emergirem.

Assim surgiu o *The Simple Logging Facade for Java* ([SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)). Ele cria uma abstração para diferentes implementações de log do Java, tais como java.util.logging, logback and log4j.

Com o SLF4J, você pode usá-lo no seu código da seguinte maneira:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassName.class);
```

Exemplo:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
    logger.info("Hello World");
  }
}
```

E depois determinar qual a implementação de log que deseja, adicionando a biblioteca desejada no *classpath* da sua aplicação. A opção mais comum atualmente [parece ser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562965/what-is-the-difference-between-log4j-slf4j-and-logback) o Logback.

Em um projeto "normal", estas bibliotecas são adicionadas usando Maven ou Gradle. No Maven, você pode adicionar o Logback da seguinte maneira:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Que ele trará logback-core (implementação) e slf4j-api (interface) ao seu projeto.

## Como fazer um bom log para produção?

Em ambiente de produção nem sempre podemos contar com o acompanhamento detalhado da execução dos processos internos. Porém, o bom uso do log pode nos trazer quase todas as informações que precisamos para diagnosticar problemas.

Existem várias dicas para isto. Alguns pontos importantes a se observar:

- Não logar várias vezes o mesmo erro. Isto gera muita confusão ao tentar entender a origem do erro e distinguir um erro do outro.
- Procure logar várias informações do que está ocorrendo nas etapas importantes dos principais processos da sua aplicação. Isto te ajudará muito a compreender quais dados estão sendo usados e por quais caminhos do seu software eles estão passando.
- Colocar o nível de severidade correto do log. Para informações que possam ser úteis para quem está vendo o log, como acompanhar a execução de determinado item, usar `INFO`. Para avisos que podem ser importantes, usar `WARN`. Para casos de erro, usar `ERROR`.
- Não logar informações sensíveis ou pessoais (CPF, e-mail, etc) sem, no mínimo, mascarar a informação. A [LGPD entra em vigor em 2020](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_Ato2015-2018/2018/Lei/L13709.htm) e temos que ter cuidado com as informações do usuário.